# Handling newt callbacks

Tags: c, linux, widget

I am having a problem with callbacks in newt . When I run the following example, nothing happens when I click the button:

```
#include <newt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void b1Callback(newComponent co, void * data)
{
    //invoke another form
}

void main(void)
{
    newtComponent form, b1, b2;
    newtInit();
    newtCls();

    newtOpenWindow(10, 5, 40, 6, "Button Sample");

    b1 = newtButton(10, 1, "Ok");
    b2 = newtCompactButton(22, 2, "Cancel");
    newtComponentAddCallback(b1, b1Callback, NULL);
    form = newtForm(NULL, NULL, 0);
    newtFormAddComponents(form, b1, b2, NULL);

    newtRunForm(form);

    newtFormDestroy(form);
    newtFinished();
}
```

What I want to do is when I click the button another form shows up. Any hints how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did to check if a button was pressed, I don't know if will help you  but I didn't put to work a callback

- Set up a variable as `newtComponent answer`
- Call this function `answer = newtFormGetCurrent(form);`
- and check if answer was my b1 button  `if( answer == b1 )`.